# Vb 6.0 Move mouse cursor to prevent sleep

Tags: vb6, mousemove

i need to run a vb program which will copy all the data from different production database to our reporting database. it will run atleast for 5 hours . so in order to prevent the machine to go to sleep how can i move mouse cursor by 1 pixed at specified interval of time . as per my client company laws i cant do this in the computer power settings. so im trying to do within my program itself.

i tried with sendkeys ie by sending down arrow at specified interval of time but it is causing problem for me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Enum Execution_State
    ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = &H1
    ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = &H2
    ES_USER_PRESENT = &H4
    ES_CONTINUOUS = &H80000000

End Enum
Declare Sub SetThreadExecutionState Lib "kernel32" (ByRef esFlags As EXECUTION_STATE)
Public Sub DoNotSleep()
    SetThreadExecutionState(esFlags:=Execution_State.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED Or Execution_State.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED Or Execution_State.ES_CONTINUOUS)
End Sub
```

picked from http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?492366-How-to-run-a-very-long-SQL-statement

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the [PowerQuerySuspend Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261106%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) of the standard VB6 **SysInfo control**?

This allows your program to cancel autosleep or even user-initiated sleep requests (unlike the older `SetThreadExecutionState` API call).